# AS3 Combobox Volume Calculator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, combobox, volume

I'm trying to create an AS3 volume calculator using 2 comboboxes, one for height and the other for diameter. The values for these being 600mm to 2000mm in increments of 100 for height, and 300mm to 600mm in increments of 50 for diameter, with the final number being outputted into a textinput.

I've already figured out the calculation of the volume for this particular shape which is a cylinder with a hemisphere attached to the top, the formula being;

**(height-190) * (diameter-6) / 2 * (diameter-6) / 2 * 3.141 / 1000000**

190 = height of the hemisphere

6 = tolerance

Would anyone have any idea on how I would go about doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding the combobox dataproviders (a list of the values they contain) to the `fx:declarations` tag:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  <s:ArrayList id="height_data">
    <fx:int>600</fx:int>
    <fx:int>700</fx:int>
    <fx:int>800</fx:int>
    <fx:int>900</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1000</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1100</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1200</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1300</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1400</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1500</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1600</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1700</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1800</fx:int>
    <fx:int>1900</fx:int>
    <fx:int>2000</fx:int>
  </s:ArrayList>
  <!-- similar list for diameter -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Then add two comboboxes, as well as an area for output to the form (here stacked in a `VGroup`, but you can arrange them however you want):

```
<s:VGroup>
  <s:ComboBox id="shape_height" dataProvider="{height_data}"
              change="calculate_volume()"></s:ComboBox>
  <s:ComboBox id="shape_diameter" dataProvider="{diameter_data}"
              change="calculate_volume()"></s:ComboBox>
  <s:TextArea id="output"></s:TextArea>
</s:VGroup>
```

And then create a function which performs the calculation:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    public function calculate_volume():void {
      var height:int = parseInt(shape_height.selectedItem);
      var diameter:int = parseInt(shape_diameter.selectedItem);
      if(!isNaN(height) && !isNaN(diameter)) {
        // perform calculation
        // store answer in volume variable
        output.appendText(volume.toString() + "\n");
      }
    }
  ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: <fx:int>600</fx:int>, <fx:int>700</fx:int>, ... ,<fx:int>2000</fx:int> Oh, it looks so ugly. You should use loop.

Comment: @AtomicRobot or just a textbox with input validation, but the OP specifically asked for a ComboBox. Typically, the values they contain won't be an ordered list of integers.